# Поиск слова в строке с разными окончаниями

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

У меня не давно возникла ситуация поиска слова в строке при помощи регулярного выражения. Проблема в том, что у слова могут быть различные окончания так же искомое слова может находиться в любой части строки как и в начале, середине так и в конце.

Comment: @Артем Борькин, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

[Lingua_Stem_Ru](http://forum.php.su/topic.php?forum=33&topic=754) . Строил поиск по сайту на основе этой библиотеки. Умеет выделять корни из слов.